# How can i display all my data on array on object

Tags: java

i want to create a method that displays all the data on the array of objects i made.
i manage to create a search specific through the help of people in here.
can i re use his code?? how? The method i want to create is at the last part.
How can i display all my data on array on object

```
import java.util.Dictionary;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestMouse {

    private static Dictionary<String, Mouse> mouseList = new Hashtable<String, Mouse>(); 

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        menu();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public static void menu() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int choice;
        do {
            System.out.println("CMPE 325 Student Record Holder System");
            System.out.println("--------------------------------");
            System.out.println("1.Add Student");
            System.out.println("2.View Records");
            System.out.println("3.Update Students");
            System.out.println("4.Get Average");
            System.out.println("5.Exit");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("--------------------------------");
            System.out.print("Enter your choice: ");
            choice = input.nextInt();

            switch (choice) {

            case 1:
                record();
                break;
            case 2:
                display();
                // display();
                break;
            case 3:
                menu();
                // update();
                // break();
            case 4:
                menu();
                // average();
                // break();
            case 5:
                break;
            default:
                continue;
            }

        } while (choice != 5);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Good-Bye");

    }

    // end of menu(); method.
    // ------------------------------------------------------------
    @SuppressWarnings({ "resource", "unused" })
    public static void record() {

        Scanner Input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int total;

        System.out.println("How many students you are going to input? ");
        total = Input.nextInt();

        Mouse[] keyboard = new Mouse[total];

        for (int index = 0; index < total; index++) {
            String space;

            keyboard[index] = new Mouse();

            System.out.printf("Student[%d]", index + 1);

            System.out.println();

            System.out.println("");
            space = Input.nextLine();

            System.out.println("ID Number: ");
            keyboard[index].setId(Input.nextLine());

            System.out.println("First Name: ");
            keyboard[index].setFirstName(Input.nextLine());

            System.out.println("Middle Name: ");
            keyboard[index].setMiddleName(Input.nextLine());

            System.out.println("Last Name: ");
            keyboard[index].setLastName(Input.nextLine());

            System.out.println("Degree: ");
            keyboard[index].setDegName(Input.nextLine());

            System.out.println("Year Level: ");
            keyboard[index].setYear(Input.nextInt());

            //Save current object
            mouseList.put(keyboard[index].getId(), keyboard[index]);
        }

        for (int index2 = 0; index2 < total; index2++) {
            System.out.printf("Student[%d]", index2 + 1);
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("ID Number:" + keyboard[index2].getId());
            System.out.println("Name:" + keyboard[index2].getFirstName() + " "
                    + keyboard[index2].getMiddleName() + " "
                    + keyboard[index2].getLastName());
            System.out.println("Degree:" + keyboard[index2].getDegName());
            System.out.println("Year Level:" + keyboard[index2].getYear());
        }
    }

    public static void specific() {
        String id = "";
        System.out.println("Enter an Id Number");
        Scanner Input = new Scanner(System.in);
        id = Input.nextLine();

        Mouse mouse = mouseList.get(id);
        if (mouse != null) {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("ID Number:" + mouse.getId());
            System.out.println("Name:" + mouse.getFirstName() + " "
                    + mouse.getMiddleName() + " "
                    + mouse.getLastName());
            System.out.println("Degree:" + mouse.getDegName());
            System.out.println("Year Level:" + mouse.getYear());
        }
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public static void display(){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int choice;


            System.out.println("--------------------------------");
            System.out.println("1.View List");
            System.out.println("2.View Specific Record");
            System.out.println("3.Exit");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("--------------------------------");
            System.out.print("Enter your choice: ");
            choice = input.nextInt();

            switch (choice) {

            case 1:
                displayall();
                break;
            case 2:
                specific();
                break;
            case 3:
                menu();
                break;

            }
}

 this part is the one im talking about. i hope u can help me
 public static void displayall(){

        String id = "";
        System.out.println("Enter an Id Number");
        Scanner Input = new Scanner(System.in);
        id = Input.nextLine();

        Mouse mouse = mouseList.get(id);
        if (mouse != null) {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("ID Number:" + mouse.getId());
            System.out.println("Name:" + mouse.getFirstName() + " "
                    + mouse.getMiddleName() + " "
                    + mouse.getLastName());
            System.out.println("Degree:" + mouse.getDegName());
            System.out.println("Year Level:" + mouse.getYear());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Two things:  you shouldn't be using `Dictionary` as an interface, and `Hashtable` is unnecessary as this does not need any thread safety.

Comment: somebody from here suggested me to do that way in order for me to find the specific id number.

it works fine but i want to create a method that shows all the data on my array of object..

Comment: `Hashtable` is synchronized, so you won't get very good performance.  Use a `HashMap` instead.  Also, you're not working with an array - you're working with a `Dictionary`.  Those two data types are radically different; it's important to know the difference for the future.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're using [the legacy `Dictionary` interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Dictionary.html), this gets a bit annoying, but it's possible to do this.

What you want to do is create an `Enumeration` of your elements, then iterate over that.  The instance is provided by calling `Dictionary#elements()`, or more specifically, `mouseList.elements()`.

You then iterate over it [as prescribed by `Enumeration`.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Enumeration.html)

It would actually be a lot easier if `Mouse` also overrode `toString()`, as that's the best way to print those sorts of complex objects.

Lastly, you make a lot of unnecessary calls in that method - you don't care about an ID or anything like that.  You'll also not need to check for `null`, since if it's not in the set of elements, it won't be in the `Enumeration`.

If you want to get a little more modern...then use a `Map` instead.  `Hashtable` already uses the `Map` interface, so you won't need to change your concrete object (although I would strongly recommend it).  Iterating over the elements of a `Map` becomes a call to [`Map#entrySet()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet%28%29) with a little more work.

Comment: i have the toString on my other class.

i dont really know whats dictionary enterface.
so i need to change my codes for this? i hope ull teach me how.:)

Comment: Why are you using an interface that you don't fully understand?  That's a little scary.